# How to change the limit of toFixed() function in js?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to use standard `toFixed()` function with an arbitrary number (official allows using values between 0 and 20)

I don't know how to change the limit, so I found this library allowing to specify an arbitrary number:

https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/blob/master/big.js

I don't want to use the whole library just to able to run this one function. Please help me to understand how does this library implementing this arbitrary length `toFixed()` function?

### update:

For example in python, a module called Decimal can calculate as many floating digits as you want:

```
>>> num1 = 4857932878236943867839468934782
>>> num2 = 1328768938470-2699462978
>>> result = Decimal(num1) / Decimal(num2)
>>> result
3663407512215411920.125441595041830470639118971082230413476294397448265790489938870721
```

Comment: toPrecision goes up to 100, is that enough?

Comment: _"how does this library implementing this arbitrary length toFixed() function?"_ You've already linked the repository with the code... [`.toFixed()`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/blob/master/big.js#L1070) uses [`.format()`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/blob/master/big.js#L121)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use simple function

```js
var numberStr = '20.83953272434765327423485345342342345';

function toFixed(nbr, precision) {
    let nSplit = nbr.split('.');
    return nSplit[0] + '.' + nSplit[1].substring(0, precision);
}
console.log( toFixed(numberStr, 22) );

//or you could extend String.prototype as

String.prototype.toLongFixed = function(precission) {
    let split = this.split('.');
    return split[0] + '.' + split[1].substring(0, precission);
}

console.log( numberStr.toLongFixed(33) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there a way to make it actually calculate the floating point digits, for example:         

`x / y = 125.836897389673476....{calculate to digit 100}` ?

Comment: I updated the question, with an example from Python, where it actually calculates the floating digits, could you take a look please?

Comment: If you do `x/y` where `x` and `y` are numbers the result will be truncated to 20 significant digits in Javascript.  So you would need a function which would pass two arguments as strings, then divide them at arbitrary precision .  I don't know a library that would do that.